# How to save multi date and time in node programmatically?

Tags: nodes, datetime

I want to save multi Date value in a node programmatically.

```
$node->field_event_date['und'][0]['value'] =?;
$node->field_event_date['und'][0]['value2'] =?;
```

getting the below value after print the form_state

```
[field_event_date] => Array
                        (
                            [und] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [show_todate] => 1
                                            [value] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [date] => 07/02/2015
                                                    [time] => 10:30AM
                                                )

                                            [value2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [date] => 07/02/2015
                                                    [time] => 12:30PM
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

Getting error

```
$node->field_event_date['und'][0]['value'] = 
    $form_state['input']['line_item_fields']['field_event_date']['und'][0]['value']['date'];

$node->field_event_date['und'][0]['value2'] = $form_state['input']['line_item_fields']['field_event_date']['und'][0]['value2']['date'];
```

But i need both date and time. I think i need to combine date and time and convert it into time stamp to save but do not understand how to combine and convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If converting the two is your problem following may help you

```
foreach ($form_state['values']['field_event_date']['und'] as $key=> $value) {
  $node->field_event_date['und'][$key]['value'] = strtotime($form_state['values']['field_event_date']['und'][$key]['value']['date'] . ' ' . $form_state['values']['field_event_date']['und'][$key]['value']['time'])
}
```

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) should be good enough.

I am assuming you are doing node_save() some where.

Comment: glad it helped you :)